# Change project file structure after migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio gradle structure

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-adt, project-structure, build.gradle

I have migrated a project from Eclipse. The project still has the "old" project file structure from eclipse (see http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html). Is there a way to automatically change the file structrue to the new system (see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)? If I understand http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html Project Structure section correctly this should have happended when migrating but it did not
 (maybe a mistake by me).
So once again my questions: is it possible to change the file structure automatically? If not, what do I have to change? What do I have to change in the build.gradle? What are obsolete files / directories?

Thanks!

Stephan

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 4):

While migrating your project from Eclipse to Android Studio, **no change have been done on project structure**. The only that have changed are new .iml and .gradle files.

**Your java code stays in** `project/src/` **folder**, and has not been moved in `project/src/main/java` folder (like in a new created project from AndroidStudio).

**Your** `AndroidManifest` **file also stays in the** `project/` **folder** and has not been moved in `project/src/main/` folder (like in a new created project from AndroidStudio).

At migration, the `build.gradle` file is customized in order to be able to compile with the old structure is described in the gradle documentation : [Configuring the Structure](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Configuring-the-Structure)

For a new created project in AndroidStudio, the sourceSets part of the build.gradle file :

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/resources']
}
```

For a migrated project from Eclipse, the sourceSets part of the build.gradle file must be that :

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

With that, you should be able to customize your project structure and build accordingly.

Comment: Why is Eclipse not migrating to Studio with main? What's the reason? Pros/Cons?

Comment: I am not sure but I think this is for retrocompatibility  : perhaps Ant is not able to compile idea-style projects (with main folder). You can do it manually and then simplify your build.gradle file

Comment: I did it manually, a bit tricky but it worked (generated a dummy project in Studio for comparison), would be good with an option to choose... Thanks...

Comment: did the same thing : a good way to learn how an idea project is made.